# Warpscript: Operation count exceeded maximum of 100000

Tags: time-series, warpscript

I encountered the following error with warpscript

> ERROR line #1 in section '[TOP]': Exception at statement '' in section '[TOP]' (Operation count (100002) exceeded maximum of 100000) (Operation count (100002) exceeded maximum of 100000)

This minimal code reproduces the problem:

```
0 1 100000 <% + %> FOR
```

Is there a simple way to get around the operation count limit or do I have to split my process into multiple scripts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [AUTHENTICATE](https://www.warp10.io/doc/AUTHENTICATE) followed by [MAXOPS](https://www.warp10.io/doc/MAXOPS) to raise the operation count limit up to the hard limit of the Warp 10 platform you are using.

For example, if you are using the public [Warp 10 sandbox](https://sandbox.senx.io/), by default you are restricted to 100,000 operations, but the hard limit on this platform is 2,000,000 operations. At the beginning of your script, you can do:

```
'<your-read-token>' AUTHENTICATE 2000000 MAXOPS
```

If you have access to the configuration file of the Warp 10 platform you are using, you can also modify the hard limit above that number by modifying the key `warpscript.maxops.hard`.

More information about WarpScript safeguard limits are available on this [link](https://warp10.io/content/03_Documentation/04_WarpScript/03_Limits).

Answer (score 2):

As a complement, it should be noted that the limit in number of operations your WarpScript program can execute is there as a safeguard for multi-tenant environments.

The default values are pretty conservative but can be modified by setting the following configuration properties and restarting your Warp 10 instance:

```
warpscript.maxops = ...
warpscript.maxops.hard = ...
```

If you are using Warp 10 in a single tenant environment, you can bump those values to multi-billion levels.